# How to get/call Joomla 4 custom fields into module

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-4

I tried below code

```
<?php

$article_id = 2;

$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Article', 'ContentModel');
$article = $model->getItem($article_id);

JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
$fields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.article', $article, true);

foreach ($fields as $key => $field)
{
   echo $field->title . ' : ' . $field->rawvalue. ' <br> ';
}

?>
```

I want to fetch/get the fields and their values individually. also tried

```
$article_id = Factory::getApplication()->input->getInt('id');
```

but giving me error. please guys help me out.

Comment: `but giving me error` Please [edit] your question to include the exact error message that you are receiving.

Comment: I am not getting any error... i need support..

Comment: Can you please provide some debugging details such as dumping `$article` and `$fields`?  It is important that you narrow your support question to the earliest point of error.  Telling us what _is_ working as desired helps volunteers to better understand your problem and confidently suggest a resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are talking about a module, and your code and comments indicate that you are trying to get a specific article by its ID, your module helper should look like:

```
<?php

namespace Joomla\Module\YourModuleName\Site\Helper

\defined('_JEXEC') or die;

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\Component\Fields\Administrator\Helper\FieldsHelper;

abstract class YourModuleNameHelper
{
    // I saw in your comment before, you trying get the
    // ID of the article using the url param
    // so I will assume you want to get the article ID
    // when you are in a article view
    public static function getArticle(&$params)
    {
        $app = Factory::getApplication();
        if (
            $app->input->get('option') === 'com_content'
            && $app->input->get('view') === 'article'
        ) {
               // Save to here all the datas you need return
               $items = new \stdClass;

               // Get the article ID
               $article_id = $app->input->getInt('id');

               // Set application parameters in model
               $appParams = $app->getParams();
               
               // The article model
               $model = $app->bootComponent('com_content')->getMVCFactory()->createModel('Article', 'Site', ['ignore_request' => true]);
               
               // Please, use any other filter as you need
               $model->setState('params', $appParams);
               $model->setState('filter.published', 1);
               $model->setState('article.id', (int) $article_id);

               $article = $model->getItem();

               // Get the custom fields
               $fields = [];
               $jcfields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.article', $article);
               if (!empty($jcfields)) {
                   foreach ($jcfields as $field) {
                       $fields[$field->name] = $field;
                   }
               } 
               
               $items->fields = $fields;
       
               // rest of the code... like get the title, introtext etc

               return $items;    
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you discovered an answer yourself but this is what I do in J4 to get custom fields:

```
use \Joomla\Component\Fields\Administrator\Helper\FieldsHelper;

FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.article', $article);
```

Then you can cycle through the returned fields in your foreach.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello  Glenn, No i didn't get the answer yet as joomla documentation is so outdated(i mean not updated)..

Comment: I tried your code in my module but it's not working...  

<?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) : ?>
<?php echo $item->customtitle; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

error: Using $this when not in object context

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem, based on great help from the Joomla forum:
https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=831&p=3677225

Setting the namespace with a use statement was not working for me.

Here is the final standalone example:

```
namespace some\custom\namespace;

define('JOOMLA_MINIMUM_PHP', '7.2.5');
define('_JEXEC', 1);

// Just to show your example can live in any sub-folder of "its own"
define('JPATH_BASE', __DIR__ . "/../../../../");
include_once JPATH_BASE . "/includes/defines.php";
include_once JPATH_BASE . "/includes/framework.php";

$container = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getContainer();

$container->alias('session.web', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias('session', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias('JSession', 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\CMS\Session\Session::class, 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\Session\Session::class, 'session.web.site')
    ->alias(\Joomla\Session\SessionInterface::class, 'session.web.site');

$app = $container->get(\Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::class);

\Joomla\CMS\Factory::$application = $app;

\JLoader::register('JNamespacePsr4Map', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/namespacemap.php');
(new \JNamespacePsr4Map)->load();

$app->createExtensionNamespaceMap();

use \Joomla\Component\Fields\Administrator\Helper\FieldsHelper;

// Get data for the logged-in user
$user = \Joomla\CMS\Factory::getApplication()->getSession()->get('user');

if ($user->id != NULL) {
  // User logged in, get the custom fields data
  $customFields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_users.user', $user, 0);
  echo "<pre>USER:" . PHP_EOL;
  var_dump($user);
  echo PHP_EOL . "<hr />CUSTOMFIELDS:" . PHP_EOL;
  var_dump($customFields);
  echo "</pre>";
}
else {
  echo "User not logged in.";
}
```